# Using Angular values in a pie chart

Tags: javascript, angularjs, charts, pie-chart

I have length values derived from a table using ng-repeat.  I would like to use these values in a pie chart but can't figure out how to do so.  Here are my values:

```
<table >

<tr style="background-color:#575757; padding:10px">
    <th width="80">PM Alert Green</th>

  </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="pmalert in pmalertcountgreen = (sites |  filter : {pmAlert: 'green' })">

        <td>{{pmalert.pmAlert}}</td>

    </tr>
</table>

<table >

<tr style="background-color:#575757; padding:10px">
    <th width="80">PM Alert</th>



  </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="pmalert in pmalertcount = (sites |  filter : {pmAlert: 'red' })">

        <td>{{pmalert.pmAlert}}</td>

    </tr>
</table>

<h3>PM Alert Filtered: {{pmalertcount.length}} </h3>
<h3>PM Alert Filtered: {{pmalertcountgreen.length -1}} </h3>
```

Here is the pie chart I would like to use:

```
angular.module('plunker', ['angularCharts']);

function PiechartCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.config = {
title: 'Site Phases:',
tooltips: true,
labels: true,
mouseover: function() {},
mouseout: function() {},
click: function() {},
legend: {
  display: false,
  //could be 'left, right'
  position: 'right'
}
  };

  $scope.data = {
series: ['Sales', 'Income', 'Expense', 'Laptops', 'Keyboards'],
data: [{
  x: "",
  y: [100],
  tooltip: "Pre-Submittal"
}, {
  x: "Zoning",
  y: [500],
  tooltip: "In Zoning"
}, {
  x: "Building",
  y: [200],
  tooltip: "In Building"
}, {
  x: "Construction",
  y: [54],
  tooltip: "In Construction"
}]
};
}
```

Here is the HTML part:

```
   <div ng-controller="PiechartCtrl">
 <div 
data-ac-chart="'pie'" 
data-ac-data="data" 
data-ac-config="config" 
class="chart">
  </div>
```

or please let me know if there is a better way of doing this.  Thank you.

Comment: You "have length values derived from a table" - what does that mean ?

Comment: sirrocco - I want to pull the number of items that have a green alert and red alert and use those results form the table in a pie chart.